# Finding MST with a given path (C++)

Tags: c++, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

I have a code for finding MST which would include a given path to MST, which gives me correct weight of MST (I know what the output is supposed to be). I tried to rewrite one part of the code to use `std::map` instead of `std::vector` for more efficient look-up (will become clear from the code below), but now it gives wrong answer, and despite looking into it for few hours, I am unable to understand where did I make a mistake. Any help with locating a bug will be appreciated.

Old version that uses `vector<Edge>`. Goes through the vector of all edges (`m_all_edges`). If an edge `e` is in `vector<Edge> path`, adds it to MST (`m_mst`). Otherwise, adds it to candidate edges for MST (`m_edges`).

```
void MSTPath::m_add_shortest_path_old(vector<Edge> path){
    for (auto e : path){
        m_graph->union_vu(e.get_node(),e.get_opposite_node(-1));
    }
    for (auto e : m_all_edges){
        if (tempfunc(e,path)) m_mst.push_back(e);
        else m_edges.push_back(e);
    }
}

bool MSTPath::tempfunc(Edge e, vector<Edge> path){
    for (auto edge : path){
        if((edge.get_node()==e.get_node())&&(edge.get_opposite_node(-1)==e.get_opposite_node(-1))) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Version with `std::map`.

```
void MSTPath::m_add_shortest_path(map<Edge,int> path_map){
    for (auto const& x : path_map){
        Edge e = x.first;
        m_graph->union_vu(e.get_node(),e.get_opposite_node(-1));
    }
    for (auto const& x : m_all_edges_map){
        if ((path_map.count(x.first)>0)||(path_map.count(x.first.reversed())>0)) m_mst.push_back(x.first);
        else m_edges.push_back(x.first);
    }
}
```

Function for finding MST (called after calling `m_add_shortest_path` / `m_add_shortest_path_old`).

```
int MSTPath::m_compute_mst(){
    sort(m_edges.begin(),m_edges.end(),[](Edge e1, Edge e2) { return e1.weight < e2.weight; });
    int i = 0;
    int mst_size = m_mst.size();

    int mst_weight = 0;
    int v,u;
    for (Edge e : m_mst) mst_weight += e.weight;

    while (mst_size<m_N-1){
        Edge edge = m_edges[i++];
        v = m_graph->find(edge.get_node());
        u = m_graph->find(edge.get_opposite_node(-1));
        if (u!=v){
            mst_size++;
            mst_weight += edge.weight;
            if (mst_weight>=min_mst_weight) return numeric_limits<int>::max();
            m_mst.push_back(edge);
            m_graph->union_vu(v,u);
        }
    }
    return mst_weight;
}
```

From what I see, both function get exactly the same `m_mst` (and starting `mst_weight`) and the same `m_edges` (but in different order). But ordering should not be a problem for the algorithm (except for ordering by weight, but this is handles in `m_compute_mst`), right?

`Edge` class:

```
class Edge{
public:
    Edge(int v_e, int u_e, int w){
        v = v_e;
        u = u_e;
        weight = w;
    }

    int get_node() const { return v; }
    int get_opposite_node(int k) const {
        if ((k==v) || (k==-1)) return u;
        else return v;
    }

    Edge reversed() const {
        return Edge(u,v,weight);
    }

    bool operator<(const Edge& e) const {
        if (this->get_node()<e.get_node()) return true;
        else if (this->get_node()==e.get_node()) return this->get_opposite_node(-1)<e.get_opposite_node(-1);
        else return false;
    }

    int v, u, weight;
};
```

**Yes, I know that passing by value makes additional copies. This is a temporary version.**

Comment: `map<Edge,int>`, what are you mapping Edges to ?

Comment: To nothing (for now, at least; just to 0). I just use map to check if map contains the given key (Edge) in O(logN).